# Google Search Console Reporting Errors for Language-Specific Pages Despite Passes in Other Verification Tools

Tags: html, css, internationalization, google-search-console

I have a problem with the Google Search Console.

The main page `/index.htlm` is receiving perfect test results and is being indexed.
I can also verify this using https://search.google.com/test/mobile-friendly
Also, all other tools I used to verify report no errors, like webhint, LightHouse, W3 Validator etc.

In the root directory there is only index.html, sitemap.xml and robots.txt.
There are two main subdirectories: `/assets`, and `/images`, holding stylesheets, javascripts, webfonts and image files. In the website code I didn't use relative paths to address resources.

The root also holds a sub directory for each language version: `/en` `/es` `/de` etc.
Each of the subdirectories contains a language-specific modified copy of index.html and two symbolic links:

```
assets -> ../assets
images -> ../images
```

So the not language specific resources are shared among all index.html versions.

Apache server config, permissions, ownership - all is ok, and the language specific site versions show up in the browser and in devTools without any errors. Also, all possible verification tools like the listed ones report no errors. Especially I want to emphesize that 1.) Google's Mobile Friendly Test has the same result as the main index.html, showing no JS console messages, no errors, and is loading all resources correctly; and 2.) LightHouse reports a passed test "Tap targets are sized appropriately - 100% appropriately sized tap targets".

Now the problem is, that Google Search Console doesn't like these language modified pages, labels them "unusable" and reports 2 errors for each:

```
1.) Clickable elements too close together
2.) Content wider than screen
```

These errors are only reported by Google Search Console and there are no further details available. They are reported for each of the five index.html files in the subdirectories, but not for the main index.html in the root.

Visually I can't find any differences between the root's index.html and all the others (besides different language strings). I also can't find any code differences, as all pages have been pre-compiled by the same php script using identical resources.

Can anyone help me with this, please? Are there other tools that can point out exactly which areas of the page are problematic? Or could anyone have a look at it? The URL is https://breogancocinagallega.es for the main page. Append `/en` for english.